# Printing strings and variables in python

Tags: python

as you can probably tell, I am a python beginner. In this program, I am trying to use a function but instead of determining a value for minutes, I want the user to input a value. For the return command of my function, I first used a comma to separate the variables from the string, however, this literally printed the commas in the result. So instead, I used a + operation but had to turn my erstwhile integer values into strings. Is there any way I could have printed the values without turning them to strings while also avoiding the type error?

here's my code

```
   def minutes_to_hours (minutes):
        hours = minutes/60
        seconds= minutes*60 
        return str(minutes) + " minutes is equivalent to " + str(hours) + " hours" + ". This is also equivalent to " + str (seconds) + " seconds."

m= int((input ("please enter the value of minutes you want to convert "))) 
print(minutes_to_hours(m))
```

Comment: It seems like you haven't settled on what you want your function to return. It could be a tuple of `(minutes, hours, seconds)` as integers, or the string you show in the example. Both returns are reasonable, depending on what you want the caller of the function to do.

Comment: A perhaps simpler formatting is to use string interpolation i.e.  [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).  Using f-strings you have `return f"{minutes} minutes is equivalent to {hours}  hours. This is also equivalent to {seconds}  seconds."`.  You have a single string with desired variables placed in {} to have them included in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
def minutes_to_hours (minutes):
    hours = minutes/60
    seconds= minutes*60
    return "{} minutes is equivalent to {} hours. This is also equivalent to {} seconds.".format(minutes, hours,seconds)

m= int((input ("please enter the value of minutes you want to convert "))) 
print(minutes_to_hours(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, to print integers you need to convert them to strings before, so your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use comma between variables and strings but it requires changes

```
def func(m):
    s=m*60
    h=m/60
    return s,h
m= int((input ("please enter the value of minutes you want to convert "))) 
s,h=func(m)
print(m,"minutes are equivalent to",s,"seconds and",h,"hours)
```

Comment: Note that ',' automatically ads a space

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach out many other approaches will be to let your function return a list and you print the list by specifying its index.

```
def minutes_to_hours (minutes):
     hours = minutes/60
     seconds= minutes*60 
     return [minutes, hours, seconds] ## return your calculated value as list

m= int((input ("please enter the value of minutes you want to convert "))) 

result = minutes_to_hours(m)

print(f"{result[0]} minutes is equivalent to {result[1]} hours. This is also equivalent to {result[2]} seconds.")
```

Hope this helps :)